# Oracle SQL fetch previous rows based

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am stuck on how to fetch the previous row after joining multiple tables - Below is the data set after joining with multiple tables

```
CARRCD  FLTNBR     IND    DEPDATETIME
----    --------   -----  --------
AB       123       0      2020-10-29T14:00:00
AB       124       0      2020-10-29T10:00:00
AB       119       0      2020-10-29T09:00:00
AB       100       0      2020-10-29T08:00:00
AB       105       1      2020-10-29T07:00:00 ---------> Match 
AB       99        1      2020-10-29T06:00:00
AB       135       1      2020-10-29T04:00:00
AB       178       1      2020-10-29T02:00:00
```

Now once I get the above dataset after joining multiple tables, I have to find the first record whose IND matches with 1 and then return the previous record. So in the above data set
the first record which matches IND=1 is "AB 105" and then I have to return the previous record

```
AB       100       0      2020-10-29T08:00:00
```

Please help

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what error/unexpected result you obtained. Please use CTE (with clause) rather than plaintext tables to specify your input data. Or prepare dbfiddle. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.
There are missing important requirements in your question - previous record in which order (assuming `depdatetime` desc)? is `fltnbr` unique (assuming yes)? what if multiple sequences 0-1-0-1 of `ind` occurs in `depdatetime` desc ordering? It seems solution will use `lag(ind) over (order by depdatetime desc)` but no guarantee it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. multiple sequences of 0-1-0-1 will not occur and the result is sorted based on depdatetime desc.With Lag I can grab a specific value from previous record  but I have to fetch the entire previous row. . Please correct my understanding

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *first* time this happens, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(ind) over (order by depdatetime desc) as next_ind
      from t
     ) t
where t.ind = 0 and t.next_ind = 1
order by depdatetime
fetch first 1 row only;
```

However, I suspect that you want this per `carcd`.  If so, you need `partition by` and some more logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by carcd order by depdatetime) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(ind) over (partition by carcd order by depdatetime desc) as next_ind
            from t
           ) t
      where t.ind = 0 and t.next_ind = 1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that the above is quite general.  In particular, it works:

- When `ind` might have more than two values.
- When `ind` can return to `0` after `1`.
- When the first row is `1` (which is rejected as a candidate).

If the problem is more constrained, there are likely other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on additional info you provided in comment, you can locate requested row as the one which has ind=0 and is followed by row with ind=1. This is done using `lead` analytical function.

Assuming `t` is your relation, this blindly typed SQL should work:

```sql
select CARRCD,  FLTNBR,     IND,    DEPDATETIME
from (
  select t.*, lead(IND) over (order by depdatetime desc) next_ind
  from t
) x
where x.ind = 0 and x.next_ind = 1
```